# Blender 2.8 breaks mesh after save

Tags: modeling, rendering, transforms

Blender 2.8 has just had a spike in entropy; now random transforms are being applied onto meshes when loaded from a saved file. I launched blender a moment ago and this is what's shown:

[image: blender just sucks]

Yesterday, the cameras where inside the support as they should be. Today, blender moved them out. Is there a way of telling blender NOT to mess up saved meshes or at least display them as messed up before and after saving (so that I can prepare emotionally prior to modelling)?

Comment: if you scrub the animation bar, does it pop out of place?

Comment: I'll have an update ~tomorrow; unable to think straight atm